# Does every world in Minecraft have all biomes at some distance from spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

**(P.S. I already know there is a relatively similar question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26531/how-do-minecraft-biomes-work) but it didn't gave me the info I needed, apart of it being 2 years old, when MC was still beta... It could be obsolete by now...)**

I know that some seeds have very few biomes that actually have resources in them. Take, for example, `GLORIOUS`, with its infinite ocean (1.5.2, haven't checked for my new 1.6.2). Or how about `This Seed sucks` with its infinite jungle? (But that one doesn't work in the later version.)

I already know that you will always find 3 dungeons at max 1 km from your spawnpoint, but I only find villages occasionally and if I do it may take MC weeks. And how about `GLORIOUS`? Will I have to travel FOREVER to find a desert or a underwater village? Or maybe I need eons of luck to find a rare mushroom island in any random seed?

Comment: FYI, if you see an answer you think is obsolete, comment on it saying so, rather than asking the question again.

Comment: Sorry, dude.  Our process for questions of this nature is to request an update through a comment, or bounty it for an updated answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: On second look, there *was* a comment asking for an update before. Sorry I must've missed it before. The answer should be up-to-date now, but feel free to asking more clarification over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *all* biomes are still present in *all* seeds, at least in vanilla Minecraft non-superflat maps.

"Infinite" biomes are most likely not so, and will end eventually, even if the given biome does appear much larger than normal due to the same biome being randomly assigned. However, identical seeds will produce vastly different maps for many different versions of Minecraft because when terrain generation changes, the worlds generated differ completely.

Your comment about dungeons (which I assume refer to [strongholds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold)—[dungeons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dungeon) have spawners in them and are also generated randomly) is still true, I believe. There was some talk about removing this preset spawn pattern and limit, but I don't see evidence that it's made its way into the game.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific seed of interest, you can use the tool Amidst to determine distances to important landmarks or biomes.