# I've just happened to come across some biomes, and I want to know how rare it is

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've found a Lukewarm Ocean where the closest shore is Ice Spikes.

- Shattered Savanna
- Modified Wooded Badlands Plateau
- Desert Lakes
- Gravelly Mountains
- Snowy Tundra Hills
- Snowy Taiga Hills

Since my friend always bully me for my survival world being so "plain" I'd like to have some rarer biomes so I can stop him.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/218827/143571

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Wrigglenite's comment

Answer (score 16):

The rarity of the biomes you have found are listed below:

1. **Ice Spikes:** 0.11%
2. **Shattered Savanna:** 0.1%
3. **Modified Wooded Badlands Plateau:** 0.02%
4. **Desert Lakes:** 0.17%
5. **Gravelly Mountains:** 0.43%
6. **Snowy Tundra:** 1.13%
7. **Snowy Taiga Hills:** 0.13%

These results were created by generating 12,000 worlds in *Minecraft 1.13.1*. These results may vary slightly, but these are the approximate percentages. I found this information from [here](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/seeds/2924676-how-common-rare-are-all-biomes-in-minecraft-the).

Comment: Sure... this info is not from a recent source and the biomes are listed out of order. In addition, some of the rare biomes were left out (modified jungle edge, mushroom field, etc.

Comment: @Dabbingsdednow OKprogrammer listed the biomes the asker requested, in the same order the asker listed them. Maybe this selection and order would be controversial for a more generally stated question ("what biomes are rarest"), but it's a perfect fit for this specific one.

Comment: @Dabbingsdednow who cares if in the next version its 0.01% off? The point was for a rough idea, and that idea was "some of these are really rare except for the snowy tundra" or something similar, the asker isnt gonna be like "damn it that dude was 0.1% off in that forum answer, im so mad why did he do that what a loser" and if he did think that I'd question his sanity

Comment: What does a "rarity of 1%" mean?

Comment: @Myridium Take a random block off a random world, the chance it's a given "1% rarity" biome is 1%.

Answer (score 1):

The top rarest biomes go in this order (1: rarest, 11: rare).

1. Modified Jungle Edge.
2. Modified Badlands Plateau
3. Snowy Taiga Mountains
4. Mushroom Fields and Mushroom Shore.
5. Bamboo Jungle and Bamboo hills
6. Eroded Badlands
7. Giant Tree Tiaga and all variants.
8. Gravelly Hills and Gravelly Mountains
9. Ice Spikes
10. Shattered Savanna & Shattered Savanna Plateau.
11. Swamp Hills

[Source](https://rarest.org/entertainment/biomes-in-minecraft)

Comment: I formatted this answer as a list. Unfortunately, ordered lists automatically count up from the first number (in your case, the list would've gone from 11 to 21), so I reversed the list. I also added the source from your other answer. Feel free to revert my edit if you feel I shouldn't have done that.

Comment: tysm. so now i'm trying to generate a world to list every biome in the same dimension, since that ice spikes literally took 2 hours for me to find it, my pc sucks so it (and the server) crashes when I load too much chunks at a time. also found modified woodland plateau like 349k blocks, for the last 50k ended up using bots :(