# How can I identify a Taiga Biome so I can find a wolf?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to find a Wolf, and I heard that they spawn in Taiga biomes. Can anyone tell me where a Taiga biome is, and/or what they look like?

If you don’t know where the Taiga biome is, please tell me where the Forest biome is.

Comment: It's pretty similar-looking to the Plains and Forest biomes, so it might be hard to tell unless you have a map mod or something. https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/File:TaigaBE.png

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26531/how-do-minecraft-biomes-work)

Comment: Hi @tszhimMak, welcome to the site! I've edited your question slightly so that it better reflects what you want to do (i.e. find a wolf). If this is not what you wanted you can always change it back by visiting the [revisions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/360684/revisions) page and clicking 'rollback' on the version you wish to use. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you are misunderstanding some basic features of minecraft.
Upon start a minecraft world is randomly generated by the Seed set at the start (If you did not specify one, a random number will take its place).

This results in the fact that you and I will have completely different worlds. 
Therefore noone can tell you, where you need to look without knowing your seed.

Steps to take (PC-Edition only! If anyone knows about bedrock please educate me so I can update this):

1. In your game access the chat console (<kbd>T</kbd>-Button by default)
2. Type in `/seed` and press enter
3. This will output the seed of your world, copy that down to any file of you chosing (like a Notepad txt file)
4. Visit one of many websites (MineAtlas, Chunkbase or many more) find their Biome tool and insert your seed there.
5. This will give you a map of your world as it should be created by your game. Here you can finde the coordinates of the biomes you want to find.
6. Now you can press <kbd>F3</kbd> while in your minecraft game to view the debug screen infos.
7. On the left there is a tag called *Position* with a triple of coordinates X/Y/Z. The coordinates you got from the website earlier reference your X and Z coordinate => ignore the Y for now.
8. Now just walk until your ingame coordinates match those found on the website (on the left in the <kbd>F3</kbd>-screen there is a "Biome"-info which displays the type of biome you are currently in, you can check the validity of the online map by that)

I hope you find your wolfes. Don't forget to bring bones to tame a cute puppy :)

Comment: you are welcome. The more others enjoy my favorite game, the longer it will be supported => the longer i can enjoy it :P Pure selfishness nothing else :D

Comment: @Chund Has taming been updated? I thought you had to use bones to tame, not flesh.

Comment: Yep. Bones to tame, flesh to heal/breed them

Answer (score 2):

Taiga biomes spawn randomly, as with any biome unless you use cheats or a specific seed, so I can't tell you HOW to find one, but I can share how to identify one.

Quick Side Note: Wolves can actually spawn in any forest biome, just specifically common in Taiga biomes.

Taiga biomes carry spruce trees, which are tall trees with a few dark green leaves on top. Sometimes, they spawn with snow in the biome. You'll know when a wolf is near because random blocks of wool or mutton will be on the ground. Just a warning: sweet berries are native to the Taiga biome, they are red berries on the ground. They're a good source of food, but they hurt you if you walk into them, similar to cacti.

There may be a Taiga Village, but not necessarily, and Taiga Villages are great sources of supplies. Keep in mind that to correctly identify a Taiga village, it will primarily be made up of spruce wood materials, and cobblestone.

Lastly, to tame your wolves, use a bone, to restore their health or put them into Love Mode, use any type of meat or rotten flesh.

I will include a photo of a Taiga Biome: [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find one legitimately, you can do what ava said, but the simplest way would just be to use the `locatebiome` command. You can learn more about `locatebiome` here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/locatebiome

For some additional information on Taiga biomes, you can check this page out: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Taiga